# Intellij doesn't show changed files in "Log of Version Control tab"

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, mercurial

Intellij correctly shows log of version control. But when I click to specific pull request (by other people) and try to see the change list of the commit, it's loading forever and doesn't show the changed files. See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since anyone didn't answer the question, I'd like to post the solution I found.

In IntelliJ settings -> Version Control -> Mercurial instead of putting hg.exe from Mercurial folder in Program Files put hg.exe from TortoiseHg.

[image]